# Regular expressions to structure a non structure texte file

Tags: javascript, regex

I am new to regular expression and i need to extract some data from the following file :

```
Card number: 604861*********3997, SEQ: 175
Current session ID: 175
21/01/2021 08:46:49 : Selected language : ENG
21/01/2021 08:46:49 : Chip application : NO Active 
 21/01/2021 09:53:03 : Returned code : 0
 21/01/2021 09:53:03 : Pin entered
 21/01/2021 09:53:09 : Transaction selected: FastCash 40000 on ATM: Y6652114
 21/01/2021 09:53:10 : Returned code : 0
21/01/2021 09:53:13  : FastCash Authorization requested
21/01/2021 09:53:14  : FastCash Authorized
Returned code : 0, STAN: 686817
21/01/2021 09:53:27  : Cash dispensed
21/01/2021 09:53:28  : Card ejected
21/01/2021 09:53:29  : Card taken
21/01/2021 09:53:32  : Dispense details:
->cass 1: 0 x 5000 MGA, cass 2: 4 x 10000 MGA
->cass 3: 0 x 10000 MGA, cass 4: 0 x 20000 MGA
------->Total cash dispensed: 40000 MGA
21/01/2021 09:53:32  : Cash presented
21/01/2021 09:53:32  : Waiting for cash to be taken
21/01/2021 09:53:33  : Cash taken
21/01/2021 09:53:39  : Transaction completed
 21/01/2021 09:53:41 : Session terminated
 Card number: 604861*********3997, SEQ: 185
```

Here is the code I tried I used group capture but it does not work for some cases and it works for others, also every time I try to combine these expressions I get a "nothing to repeat error"

```
const CARD_NUMBER = /number:\s*([\d*]*)/gi;
const TRANSACTION_AMOUNT = /FastCash\s*([\d,.]*)/gi;
const TRANSACTION_CURRENCY = /Total cash dispensed:\s*(\D)*/gi;
const TERMINAL_ID = /ATM:\s*(\w*)/;
const EXTERNAL_STAN = /STAN:\s*(\d*)/i;
const TRANSACTION_DATE = /([ a-zA-Z0-9/:_-]+)? : Session terminated/i;

// or combined 
var rx = new RegExp(
  "number:s(d+*+d+).*?FastCashs(d+).*?ATM:s(w+).*?STAN:s(d+).*?completed[\r\n]+(.*?)s)",
  "gi"
);
var matches = new Array();
while ((match = rx.exec(sample)) !== null) {
  matches.push(match);
}
console.log(matches);
```

Comment: Please show the code that uses these regular expressions and that runs into the error you mention.

Comment: Hey @trincot I added the code where I tried to combine everything in order to get an array of all the wanted fields

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So here's my regex list.

The combined regex is really complex it uses a lot of non-capturing groups and it has to map over the result to remove the undefined matched groups

```js
const str = document.body.innerText;
document.body.innerText = '';
const CARD_NUMBER = /Card number:\s*(\d{19})/gi;
const TRANSACTION_AMOUNT = /FastCash\s*(\d+)/gi;
const TRANSACTION_CURRENCY = /Total cash dispensed:\s*(\d+)/gi;
const TERMINAL_ID = /ATM:\s*(\w+)/gi;
const EXTERNAL_STAN = /STAN:\s*(\d+)/gi;
const TRANSACTION_DATE = /((?:\d{2,4}\/*)+\s*(?:\d{2}:*)+)\s*:\s*Session terminated/gi;

const COMBINED = /Card number:\s*([\d\*]{19})|FastCash\s*(\d+)|Total cash dispensed:\s*(\d+)|ATM:\s*(\w+)|STAN:\s*(\d+)|((?:\d{2,4}\/*)+\s*(?:\d{2}:*)+)\s*:\s*Session terminated/gi;

console.log([...str.matchAll(CARD_NUMBER)][0][1]);
console.log([...str.matchAll(TRANSACTION_AMOUNT)][0][1]);
console.log([...str.matchAll(TRANSACTION_CURRENCY)][0][1]);
console.log([...str.matchAll(TERMINAL_ID)][0][1]);
console.log([...str.matchAll(EXTERNAL_STAN)][0][1]);
console.log([...str.matchAll(TRANSACTION_DATE)][0][1]);
console.log('Combined');
console.log([...str.matchAll(COMBINED)].map(match => match.filter(a => a)[1]));
```

```html
Card number: 6048616048616048611, SEQ: 175
Current session ID: 175
21/01/2021 08:46:49 : Selected language : ENG
21/01/2021 08:46:49 : Chip application : NO Active 
 21/01/2021 09:53:03 : Returned code : 0
 21/01/2021 09:53:03 : Pin entered
 21/01/2021 09:53:09 : Transaction selected: FastCash 40000 on ATM: Y6652114
 21/01/2021 09:53:10 : Returned code : 0
21/01/2021 09:53:13  : FastCash Authorization requested
21/01/2021 09:53:14  : FastCash Authorized
Returned code : 0, STAN: 686817
21/01/2021 09:53:27  : Cash dispensed
21/01/2021 09:53:28  : Card ejected
21/01/2021 09:53:29  : Card taken
21/01/2021 09:53:32  : Dispense details:
->cass 1: 0 x 5000 MGA, cass 2: 4 x 10000 MGA
->cass 3: 0 x 10000 MGA, cass 4: 0 x 20000 MGA
------->Total cash dispensed: 40000 MGA
21/01/2021 09:53:32  : Cash presented
21/01/2021 09:53:32  : Waiting for cash to be taken
21/01/2021 09:53:33  : Cash taken
21/01/2021 09:53:39  : Transaction completed
 21/01/2021 09:53:41 : Session terminated
```

Comment: Hey, @a.mola thank you for your response but is there a way to combine all the different regex into one that extracts everything, also you still have the same problem I had by returning results like " [ 'STAN: 686817','686817',] while am only interested in the second element i know i can get it by using [1] but it does not seem like a very reliable soltuon.

Comment: If you want to get the second element, you have to use `matchAll` then pick that with `[1]`. If not using `match` will return the whole match string

Comment: Hey @a.mola do you have any idea why the combined code works perfectly for the sample if I pass it as a string but not if I read it from a text file?

Comment: How are you getting the file? and are you sure its being parsed well?

Comment: `// read file
var fs = require("fs");
const data = "";
try {
  data = fs.readFileSync("atm_data.txt", "utf8");
} catch (e) {
  console.log("Error:", e.stack);
}` this is what i used to get the file

Comment: Could you log out what data returns, just to be sure its what you want... I know what its meant to return though. But just check the log

Comment: data returns the full-text file ( the sample I gave in my question and others, imagine the sample repeated like 10 times or more ) i want to read the file and then use the combined  regular expression to get all the matches from the text file ( these matches will later be stored as a CSV file or  in JSON format )

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230116/discussion-between-a-mola-and-souhail).